# Test Runner tab in IntelliJ 2018.3 CE not showing

Tags: java, maven, testing, intellij-idea, junit

I'm using `IntelliJ 2018.3 CE`. I have a java maven project (developed using `springboot`) in which the `JUnit` tests have already been written. However, when I try to run the tests, the output is always shown in the default run window, and NOT in the Test Runner Tab. In fact, I cannot make this window pop-up after a running a test.

I have `Junit 4.12` in the external libraries of my project (as Maven: `junit:junit:4.12`). The test folders have been appropriately flagged as test resources.

I presume it has to deal with settings in IntelliJ but even with all the effort in the world, I wasn't able to find what is causing this.

Is someone experiencing the same issue? Or does someone know how to resolve this?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: *when I try to run the tests*: how do you do that?

Comment: I right click on the src/test/java folder, then Run 'All Tests'. I have updated my original question with a screenshot. I hope this clarifies...

Comment: The tests don't run at all. The output you see, in the *Build* tab, is the output from the **compiler**, which tells you that you have compilation errors, You can't run code that doesn't even compile.

Comment: I know there are errors in it. The goals is to run the test and get a report of the which tests have failed. (the exercise is to do this, then to fix them, and re-run the report which should then no longer show the errors).

Comment: But for the tests to run, the code has to compile. If the compiler doesn't generate any byte-code because your code is not valid Java code, how could you run the byte-code? it doesn't exist. Fix the compilation errors.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok, that already makes a bit more sense to me. I will have to investigate the source code... Thanks so much!!

Comment: Start by reading the error messages. They tell you what is wrong and where.